# SQL Server : how to use SELECT results in INSERT clause of MERGE STATEMENT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to build this MERGE statement to use a result from other table in the INSERT clause, but SQL Server is complaining about the syntax. Does anyone know what the right syntax is?

```
MERGE INTO tableA AS target
USING (VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3)) AS source (column1, column2, column3) ON (source.column1 = target.column1)

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN 
       UPDATE SET column2 = @value2

WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN 
      INSERT (column1, column2, column3) 
      (SELECT TOP 1 column1, column2, column3
       FROM tableB
       WHERE column1 = @value1)
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting, i.e. where does it say the syntax problem is?

Comment: Yes, the documentation. Did you try it? Simply google for `T-SQL MERGE` to [find it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql). As for using a different table in the INSERT *why*? That's the job of the `USING` block. *It* provides the source data.

Comment: Perhaps you should use two separate UPDATE, INSERT statements?

Comment: I would highly recommend being careful when using `MERGE` functionality. There are [many known bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) and problems with `MERGE` statements. They also tend to give incredibly vague error messages as well.

Comment: The use of "top 1" without an order by clause is usually an indication that something is wrong. I'll agree with the other suggestions - you are not using the merge statement as intended and that is the source of your troubles. In fact, it is difficult to understand how not finding a row that matches a particular tuple (col1, col2, col3) results in the insertion of a mostly different set of tuples. In theory, the insert portion could fail with a "duplicate" error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the syntax in the question.

1) The `when not matched then` is followed by a `insert`/`select` show below.

```
INSERT (column1, column2, column3) 
  (SELECT TOP 1 column1, column2, column3
  FROM  tableB
  WHERE   column1 = @value1)
```

2) The `select` statement above references `tableB` that is not the `target` or `source`.

If you are trying to get the values from the variables (ex. `@value1`) into the table, your merge statement should look like this.

```
MERGE INTO tableA AS target
  USING (
    VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3)
  ) AS source (column1, column2, column3)
  ON (source.column1 = target.column1)
  WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET
      target.column2 = source.column2
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN 
  INSERT values (source.column1, source.column2, source.column3);
```

If you are honestly trying to insert from `tableB` when the `target` and `source` (values) do not match, then you will most likely have to separate the two pieces of the `merge` statement.